# Firebase "Child_added" not returning data on initial read

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I’ve got a mobile app using React JS & Firebase Realtime DB.
App retrieves data using “child_added” feature in firebase.

When the app fires up the first thing it does read in objects from firebase and push them into a local JS array.  Then it uses listeners to push any deltas to existing local array.

ISSUE
The initial read returns no data (but it used to up to some months back). It’s only when I actually add a new object does “child_added” start retrieving data. My understanding is that “child_added” on initial read will return the full object list and only return deltas thereafter?

I’ve also tried “value” instead of “child_added” but this returns noting at all

CODE

```
Const firebaseConfig = {
      apiKey: "nnnnnI",
      authDomain: "nnnnn",
      databaseURL: "https://nnnn",
      projectId: "nnnnn",
      storageBucket: "nnnnn"
}

const firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
const database = firebaseApp.database().ref('items/')

database.on('child_added', snap => {
  shoppingList.push({
    id: snap.key,
    shoppingItem: snap.val().shoppingItem
  })
```

Any help on the above would be appreciated, thank you/.

Comment: I've never seen `on('child_added'` suddenly stop working. Can you set up a minimal reproduction of the problem in a site like jsbin?

Comment: Hi Frank, thanks for your comments. As per your suggestion when I use JSBIN "value" works just fine.

I see JSBIN uses Firebase CDN whereas I'm using firebase via NPM, I'm wondering if there's an issue within my code on how I'm configuring firebase via NPM? I've included my config in the above code snippet.

Comment: Here's the relevant code generated by JSBIN .....

<script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/1.2.0-beta.2/firebase.js"></script>
var ref = new Firebase("https://,,,,,,.firebaseio.com");
ref.on('value', function(snapshot) { console.log(snapshot.val()); });

Comment: You're using an incredibly old Firebase SDK in that last comment. Please follow the instructions here to use the latest SDK: https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup. If you can't reproduce it in a jsbin, it'll be hard to help. But if you think the NPM module it part of the problem, include information about what you did with that in your question. See [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: ah brilliant thank you. Apologies I should have checked Firebase SDK version. Thanks for your help